# VBA copying and pasting charts from excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Ok, so I'm trying to write some code which will first create about 15 graphs on excel and then open a template on powerpoint and paste these graphs into each slide. I'm having multiplt issues though and I can't really seem to find out why. When I run through the code line by line by pressing f8 it works fine but the second I run the whole macro a few things happen:
1) It randomly will decide to not paste some graphs on pages
2) When trying to refer to the pasted graph via code like .shapes(3) or shapes(slide.shapes.count) I get an error message saying shapes.item: integer 3 out of range 1 to 2
3) I'm using CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") to paste the graphs as I need to keep the formatting, I can paste the graphs and position them another way but it doesn't keep the formatting which I need.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
   Sub PowerPointPresentation()
   Dim PPT As Object
   Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
   PPT.Visible = True
   PPT.Presentations.Open filename:="P:\My Documents\CM Presentation Macro\CM Presentation Template.pptm"
'copy_chart "sheet_name", 2  ' Name of the sheet to copy graph and slide number the graph is to be pasted in

Dim PPApp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object

Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
'Set PPSlide = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Slide")

Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

'Slide 1
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (1)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Country Review  YTD " & Year(Now())

'Slide 2
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (2)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " Country Review  YTD " & Year(Now())

'Slide 3
Worksheets("Pivots").ChartObjects(1).Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

i = Pivots.Range("G14").Text
j = Pivots.Range("H14").Text

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (3)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " TCV YTD " & Year(Now()) - 1 & " and " & Year(Now()) & " - by Sector"
.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Totals:" & Year(Now()) - 1 & ":" & i & "" & Year(Now()) & ":" & j
End With
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

'Slide 4
Worksheets("Pivots").ChartObjects(2).Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

i = Pivots.Range("V14").Text
j = Pivots.Range("W14").Text

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (4)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " TCV YTD " & Year(Now()) - 1 & " and " & Year(Now()) & " - by Type"
.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Totals:" & Year(Now()) - 1 & ":" & i & "" & Year(Now()) & ":" & j
End With
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

'Slide 5
Worksheets("Pivots").Range("New_TCV_YTD2014[#All]").Copy

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (5)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
With PPSlide
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
End With

Worksheets("Pivots").ChartObjects(3).Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (5)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
With PPSlide
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = r & " New TCV by AM YTD " & Year(Now())
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
End With

' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (1)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
```

Try this:

```
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(1)
```

No need to go to the slide.

When pasting a chart, try:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set oSh = .Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)(1)
    ' And now you can use oSh to position/size/otherwise work with the chart
End With
```

And you can probably do this rather than selecting anything in the workbook:

```
Worksheets("Pivots").ChartObjects(2).Copy
```

If you don't select stuff (in either app), your code will run somewhere between ten and forty-eleven bazillion times faster and will be more reliable.  And that alone might solve the other problem; the app may be busy trying to refresh after the select actions you're asking for and unable to keep up with the other stuff you ask it to do next.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, most of this has helped my code enormously. One issue I am having is that when pasting the charts onto powerpoint with the 'Set oSh =' method is that it works but it also breaks my code and I get an error message saying 'type mismatch' and despite it actually pasting it won't go past that line. Any ideas? It also doesn't keep the source formatting, but I'm a bit past trying to get that to work, I think I'll just write a macro within the powerpoint afterwards to do the formatting

Comment: Are you sure you added the (1) at the end of the Set oSh= command?  oSh is dimmed as a shape but .PasteSpecial returns a ShapeRange; the (1) at the end tells PPT to set oSh = the first shape in the returned ShapeRange.  Without it you will definitely get a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: I was yes but I found a workaround to the issue, I just did 'PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select' I'm not entirely sure why but this meant that I could refer to the object with PPSlide.Shapes(3) and move it around that way